# Creating a dictionary from a text file using each line

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, dictionary

My `.txt` file looks like this:

```
 1 2
 3 4
 5 6
 7
 a 8
 9 10
```

I need to check if both values on a line are integers if they're not it gives an error and continues.

Then change it to a dictionary using the values on the left as keys and the values on the right as values but only if both values are integers.

If they're not both integers, and key is already present I have to add a value. If the key isn't present I add both a value and a key.

Before all this I need to open the text file using raw input which gives an error if an invalid input is inserted. (I got this part working)

This is what I have so far:

```
while True:
    try:
        fileName=raw_input('File name:')
        File2=open(fileName,'r+')
        break
    except IOError:
        print 'Please enter valid file name!'

for line in File2:
    if line==int:
        continue
else:
    print 'This line does not contain a valid Key and Value'

myDict = {}
for line in File2:
    line = line.split()
    if not line:  
        continue
    myDict[line[0]] = line[1:]
    print line
```

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense. First you say you only add to a dictionary if both strings are integers, then you say _"If they're not both integers, and key is already present I have to add a value. If the key isn't present I add both a value and a key."_ - so what exactly is the requirement?

Comment: Your statements are confusing and and ambiguous. I think adding sample output for your given input will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will hopefully get you going a bit further. It is not clear what you are trying to do when the values in the file are not integers. Below shows where you can add this:

```
import os

myDict = {}

while True:
    fileName = raw_input('File name: ')
    if os.path.isfile(fileName):
        break
    else:
        print 'Please enter valid file name!'

with open(fileName, 'r') as f_input:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f_input, start=1):
        cols = line.split()
        if len(cols) == 2:
            try:
                v1 = int(cols[0])
                v2 = int(cols[1])
                myDict[v1] = v2
            except ValueError, e:
                print "Line {} does not use integers - {}, {}".format(line_number, cols[0], cols[1])
                # If they're not both integers, and key is already present I have to add a value
                # <Add that here>
        else:
            print "Line {} does not contain 2 entries".format(line_number)

print myDict
```

So for you example file, this would give you the following kind of output:

```
File name: x
Please enter valid file name!
File name: input.txt
Line 4 does not contain 2 entries
Line 5 does not use integers - a, 8
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 9: 10}
```

I would recommend you use Python's `with` command. This will automatically close the file afterwards for you.

Comment: This was exactly what I'm looking for. Sorry for the confusion English isn't my first language! Much appreciated!